# How to use the extensionId on RingCentral API with RingOut

Tags: ringcentral, ringout

I can RingOut successfully requesting:

```
https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/ring-out
```

But when I want to add the extension id I get a `CMN-102` error (`Resource for parameter [extensionId] is not found`) see request example below:

```
https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/279580017/ring-out
```

I'm pretty certain I have the correct id as I'm grabbing the `extensionId` from the request below successfully:

```
https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension
```

If anyone has run into this or can point out any potential pitfalls I would very much appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 2):

From your post and the error you are receiving, I'm assuming you are attempting to perform a RingOut with an `extensionId` that did not authorize your app. Attempting to do this will result in the error you received. Here's more information on this.

**RingOut ExtensionId Scope**

The RingOut API only supports using `extensionId` path parameter for the authorizing user extension. Because of this, all you ever need to call is the following endpoint for RingOut:

```
POST /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/ring-out
```

If you want to use the explicit `extensionId`, it needs to be the extensionId returned in the following endpoint:

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~
```

If you call the endpoint with a path `extensionId` parameter that did not authorize the access token being used, then you will receive the:

**Non-Matching ExtensionId Error**

If you attempt to perform a RingOut with a path `extensionId` value that is not the authorizing user, you will receive a HTTP status `404` error with the following body:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

{
  "errorCode": "CMN-102",
  "message": "Resource for parameter [extensionId] is not found",
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "CMN-102",
      "message": "Resource for parameter [extensionId] is not found",
      "parameterName": "extensionId"
    }
  ],
  "parameterName": "extensionId"
}
```

**How to Perform RingOut for Many Users**

To perform RingOut for many users at this time, you will need to do either of the following:

- each user will have to perform an authorization with your app, either through a login pop-up via OAuth 2.0 authorization code or implicit grant.
- alternately, you can ask them for their passwords to perform OAuth 2.0 password grant authorization.

A number of OAuth 2.0 demo apps are available on our GitHub accounts:

- https://ringcentral.github.io/tutorials/
- https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-demos-oauth

**Enhancement Request**

If you would like the ability to RingOut to any user without an active session, let us know and we can consider it as a feature enhancement. The best way is to login to our Community with your RingCentral account and post a request here:

https://devcommunity.ringcentral.com/ringcentraldev